# Recuperar objeto del LocalStorage en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, local-storage, storage

estoy realizando una pagina donde muestra productos de un array en una Card pero al momento de querer agregar mas productos al array a travez de inputs (usuario ingresa) se guarda el NUEVO PRODUCTO en el localSrorage pero al momento de actualizar la pagina se BORRA EL NUEVO PRODUCTO del localStorage y solo quedan guardados los productos de la lista original:

//funcion para agregar productos al array data

```
function createNewProduct() {
  idProduct++;
  const titleProduct = newProduct.value;
  console.log(titleProduct)
  const priceProduct = newPrice.value;
  console.log(priceProduct)
  const id = idProduct;

  const newFruit = {id:id, nombre: titleProduct, precio: priceProduct, imagen: imgSelected};

  if (id === id) {

    if (data.some(el => el.id === id)) {
        const target = data.find(el => el.id === id);
        console.log(target)
        data = data.filter(el => el.id !== id);
        console.log(data)
    }

    const nuevoNewFruit = {id:id, nombre: titleProduct, precio: priceProduct, imagen: imgSelected};
    data.push(nuevoNewFruit)
  } else {
    data.push(newFruit);
    console.log(newFruit)

  }

  console.log(data)
  dibujarProductos(data, contenedor)
  
  
}
```

//funcion que sirve para mostrar todos los productos en la pagina

```
const dibujarProductos = (data, contenedor) => {
    let acumulador = '';
    data.forEach(element => {
        acumulador += `
        
        <div class=  "card mx-auto text-bg-secondary"  style="width: 15rem;"  >
       
        <div class="cont-img">
        
            <img class ="img-main" src="${element.imagen}" class="card-img-top" alt="${element.nombre}.">
        </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">${element.nombre}</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Cantidad: ${element.cantidad}</p>
                <p class="card-text">Precio: $${element.precio}</p>
                <a href="#" onclick="agregarAlCarrito(${element.id})" class="btn btn-primary">Comprar</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        
          `
        });
        contenedor.innerHTML = acumulador;
       localStorage.setItem('data',JSON.stringify(data))
       
       
};
```

//y el HTML

```
<div id="contenedor" class="d-flex flex-wrap gap-2 mt-3 mb-3"></div>
```

```
 <!--modal para agregar productos-->

  <div  class="modal" tabindex="-1" class="modal fade" id="modalAgregar" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modalAgregarLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          
          <input type="text" id="new-product" placeholder="Product">
          <input type="text" id="new-price" placeholder="Price">
          <input type="file" name="" id="new-image">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button id="btn-new-create">Create new Object</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    
    <button id="btn-create" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modalAgregar">Create a new Product</button>
    
  </div>
```

Gracias de antemano,

Comment: agrega tu html tambien!

Comment: Hola @infinit3Loop__ ya lo acabo de agregar, espero pueda ayudar. Saludos

Comment: de donde sacas 'data'?

Comment: ¿La lista original en que momento se carga?  Si se borra el nuevo producto es porque en el rocument.ready() estas creando el local storage nuevamente con la lista original. En todo caso debería primero preguntar si existe ese localstorage y si no existe le cargas la lista original. Se me ocurre que es eso.